# Bootstrap 3 Navbar Collapse Issue

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

This is the code i am using:

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"  role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">     
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Project name</a>        
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="#nav-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="work.html">Work</a></li>

    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <li><a href="#modal-contact-form" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-contact-form">Contact</a></li>

    </ul>

    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that i can't click the 3 icon-bars! Any solution for this?

I tried different solutions of navbars, i even installed the one from bootstrap github and didn't worked!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does "can't click" mean?

Comment: @isherwood: He means that when he clicked on the interface widget formed by the three `<span>` tags with the "icon-bar" class, they don't cause the menu to expand as expected. This was due to a coding error in the `id` elsewhere (see my answer below for details). It's a common mistake.

Answer (score 4):

The ID on:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="#nav-collapse">
```

Is supposed to be:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-collapse">
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9pruK/)**

Comment: This fixes his primary problem, but it's not the whole picture. He should be using `<nav>` for his navbar.  Also, the "navbar-wrapper" really should be a class of the `<nav>` tag, not an outer `<div>`.  See the navbar section of this page: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-twitter-bootstrap-3/

Comment: @user3023073: Can you put the updated code in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/679/) ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/680/

I also added the custom.css file i am using. Maybe it's a problem with that.

Comment: When i minimize the browser window, half of the desktop, the icon bars can be clicked, the menu collapse but i can't click on any link. If i minimize the window to a smartphone view, can't click the span icons anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Your code was failing because you put a `#` character in the `id` attribute; it's only needed in the `data-target` attribute.

Here is your menu, fixed and confirmed in Firefox, Chrome, and MSIE:

```
<nav class="navbar-wrapper navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"  role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">     
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Project name</a>        
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="work.html">Work</a></li>

        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

            <li><a href="#modal-contact-form" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-contact-form">Contact</a></li>

        </ul>

    </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: It does not work. Can't click on the the span icons.

Comment: I expanded the window more, like a tablet view and now the menu expands, but can't click on any link. This pissed me off! It was working when i started coding the template, and now i am trying to figure it out since yesterday.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with my custom.css?

html,
body {
 height: 100%;
 background-color:#b4dced;
}

#wrap {
 min-height: 100%;
 height: auto !important;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto -60px;
}

#push,
#footer {
 height: 60px;
}

#footer {
 background-color:#bafa91;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
#footer {
 margin-left: -20px;
 margin-right: -20px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
}
}

Comment: I don't believe your CSS is causing the problem.  I put your CSS and my above navbar solution into a bootply and it works: http://bootply.com/96058    Clearly there is something else going on with your code that is not evident here. Perhaps you've got issues loading one of the component (jQuery, Bootstrap JS library). What browser are you using for test?

Comment: I am using Mozilla Firefox, but i also uploaded the files to my web-hosting account and tested with my iPhone.

Comment: I'm looking at the Bootply on my iPhone right now: http://bootply.com/render/96058   Tapping the three bars brings up the menu for me.  Do you care to give out the hosting URL?  I can look at the overall page and see what's going on.

Comment: I changed the bootstrap.js file to a fresh one and it's working on my desktop right now, but not working on my iPhone. Any idea?

Comment: Make sure you're using the latest Bootstrap CSS and JS. I'd recommend jQuery 1.10.x (not jQuery 2 of course) and make sure it's loading in the head.  Also, we should run your HTML against a validator to make sure there's nothing wrong with the DOM.

Comment: I already updated to the latest jQuery and Bootstrap JS.

When i minimize the browser window, half of the desktop, the icon bars can be clicked. If I minimize the window to a smartphone view, can't click the span icons anymore. Also doesn't work from my iPhone.

Comment: Can you post the URL of where the whole page is available?  (BTW, I'm behind a firewall that might prevent me from accessing it, but I'll see what I can do.)

Comment: Sorry but i can't post the link :(